# Enable c++14 in visual studio 2015 cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, c++14

I am trying to have a dynamically sized array on the stack.
I have the following code

```
int length = 0;
getLength(&someVar, &length);

char infoLog[length];
```

but I can't do it.
I originally developed the code on macOS and had no problem compiling it.
I did some research and found out c++14 supports this, but I am not sure how to turn it on in CMake (or in VS2015 community edition).

Thanks

EDIT: As drescherjm showed it wasn't actually added to the spec. Did it as per the answer below.

Comment: ***found out c++14 supports this*** I am pretty sure that is wrong. https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/3clm34/why_was_n3639_runtimesized_arrays_with_automatic/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C++14 does not support it.

Try using a dynamic container instead:

```
std::vector<char> infoLog(length);
```

If you don't want to allow resizing after creation (because the VLA doesn't), then

```
auto infoLog = std::make_unique<char[]>(length);
```

Both will use heap space to store the content, and free it automatically when the variable `infoLog` leaves scope.